# Rails 3 XML Builder / Twilio API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, ruby-on-rails-3, twilio

This Twilio API Sample code isn't working in Rails 3:

```
#voice_controller.rb

  def reminder
    @postto = BASE_URL + '/directions'

    respond_to do |format|
      format.xml { @postto }
    end
  end

#reminder.xml.builder

xml.instruct!
xml.Response do
xml.Gather(:action => @postto, :numDigits => 1) do
    xml.Say "Hello this is a call from Twilio.  You have an appointment 
        tomorrow at 9 AM."
    xml.Say "Please press 1 to repeat this menu. Press 2 for directions.
        Or press 3 if you are done."
    end
end
```

Any ideas?

Twilio seems to successfully make the phone call (I can see the params with my phone number, location, etc.) but then return this vague response code:

```
Completed 406 Not Acceptable in 0ms
```

Comment: Where do you put the XML builder file???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio doesn't send an Accept HTTP header in [its requests](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request), which causes Rails 3 to decide that it can't respond with an appropriate content type. I think the following will get around that for you though:

```
# voice_controller.rb

  def reminder
    @postto = BASE_URL + '/directions'

    render :content_type => 'application/xml'
  end
```

Answer (score 3):

Twilio employee here. There have been a bunch of changes to Rails since this original question was posted, and I wanted to share how you might tackle this problem using Rails 4, Concerns and the Twilio Ruby gem.

In the code sample below, I define the controller in `/controllers/voice_controller.rb` and include a Concern called Webhookable. The Webhookable Concern lets us encapsulate logic related to Twilio webhooks (setting the HTTP response header to text/xml, rendering TwiML, validating that requests originate from Twilio, etc) into a single module.

```
require 'twilio-ruby'

class VoiceController < ApplicationController
  include Webhookable

  after_filter :set_header

  # controller code here

end
```

The Concern itself lives in `/controllers/concerns/webhookable.rb` and is fairly simple. Right now it simply sets the Content-Type to text/xml for all action and provides a method to render the TwiML object. I haven't included the code to validate that requests are originating from Twilio, but that would be easy to add:

```
module Webhookable
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    def set_header
      response.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/xml"
    end

    def render_twiml(response)
      render text: response.text
    end

end
```

Finally, here's what your `reminder` action might look like using the Twilio gem to generate TwiML and using the Concern to render this object as text:

```
  def reminder
    response = Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
      r.Gather :action => BASE_URL + '/directions', :numDigits => 1 do |g|
        g.Say 'Hello this is a call from Twilio.  You have an appointment 
    tomorrow at 9 AM.'
        g.Say 'Please press 1 to repeat this menu. Press 2 for directions.
    Or press 3 if you are done.'
      end
    end

    render_twiml response
  end
```